# two-column dropdown menu issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-studio

I am using Bootstrap Studio, but this could be a general HTML/CSS coding question as well. I am building a search bar navigation on my home page, and I started by using a drop-down menu for users to select additional search features. Although this is a menu, it will eventually be a form to filter out additional search criteria. I am trying to create a two-column layout in this dropdown menu. My only issue is, it won't let me nest a menu item within a column or row.

I just want to know if anyone knows if there is there a more efficient way to do this? Or an alternate route for selecting parameters? I am open to using buttons as I am going for a button-like look, or checkbox/radio functions as long as the actual checkbox/radio is not visible.

Front end HTML/CSS issue

Comment: This is a two column Bootstrap menu working example: https://codepen.io/dustlilac/pen/Qwpxbp

Comment: this (using lists) worked for me! Idk why I didn't think of it, thank you!